# Open and convert woff variable font to ttf

Tags: fonts, font-forge

I have a variable font in type woff and I want open all weights in fontforge (or other software) to convert every weight to the single ttf font.

Comment: Hi. What is the font? And where did you get it?  Many fonts are available in different formats. The TTF version may already exist.

Comment: Isn't the point of a variable font that it's infinitely variable? How many TTF variants are you expecting?! (Or have I misunderstood the question and you want simply to convert the WOFF font into a single variable TTF file?)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

You're best off contacting the font's original designer and getting the file from them. Many font licenses don't allow you to convert from one format to another.